# Protractor Page Object count returning incorrectly

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, protractor, cucumber

I'm trying to write some e2e tests for an Ionic app using Protractor and Cucumber. I've followed a page object pattern, but for some reason, despite me waiting for the elements to be present, the call to `count()` is returning `0`. If I put a sleep in, however, it works. Here's my step:

```
Then('my cases should be listed', function (callback) {
  casesPage.isLoaded()
  .then(() => {
    expect(casesPage.numberOfFamilies())
      .to.eventually.equal(20)
      .and.notify(callback);
  })
});
```

And my page object

```
import { browser, $, $$, by, ElementFinder, ElementArrayFinder } from 'protractor';

export class CasesPage {

  listOfFamilies: ElementArrayFinder;

  private initializePromise: Promise<void>;

  async initialize(): Promise<void> {
    if(!this.initializePromise) {
      return this.initializePromise = new Promise<void>(async (resolve) => {
        this.listOfFamilies = $$('ul.families li.family');
        return resolve();
      });
    }
  }

  get() {
    return browser.get('/cases')
  }

  async isLoaded(): Promise<boolean> {
    await this.initialize();
    return this.listOfFamilies.isPresent();
  }

  async numberOfFamilies(): Promise<number> {
    await this.initialize();
    // browser.sleep(3000); Uncommenting this works
    return this.listOfFamilies.count();
  }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that `this.listOfFamilies.count()` return Promise that you should resolve. Just add `await` before it:

```
  async numberOfFamilies(): Promise<number> {
    await this.initialize();
    return await this.listOfFamilies.count();
  }
```

Comment: also you have a bit strange construction of page object class. It is out of scope this question.